# Parsing operators, not values, from instruction file

Tags: c, lexer

I'm using C but I guess this is a pretty language-agnostic question. Say I have an instruction file containing something like

```
IF:       OutsideTemperature > 3 && 
          InsideTemperature <= 7 && 
          DayOfWeek == Thursday
THEN:     EXECUTE(SomeFunction)
```

Assume these parameter values, including a function pointer to `SomeFunction`, can be accessed via some hashmap or something at runtime. That's easy but parsing the operators does not seem as direct.

I've heard that you can do this with some form of lexer, but this sounds rather complex (maybe it isn't?). Would it be possible to translate logical operations directly into appropriate bit masks?

Comment: Lexers generate tokens based on [some automata](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/courses/cs471/lec/cs471-03-lex.pdf). Parsers parse tokens based on some grammar syntax or expression rules. So you heard partially correct. And I'm not shy in saying I'm confused what you last question actually means. Chances are you don't need some elaborate general-purpose lexer or formal parser; but it may be worth your while to investigate how it is done, especially for a *simple* task like this. Believe me, they can get very complex *very* quickly, and learning with a simple task may be very rewarding.

Comment: I would almost certainly go for the `flex` + `bison` lexer/parser combo, but only because I know how to use both. The learning curve may be somewhat steep. The syntax of the fragment that you included in the question is quite simple, you can write your own parser in C (with `strtok`, perhaps), but it will be a pain in the back to extend it in the future.